# ASP.NET app on IIS 8 Server not talking to SQL Server 2012 database server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, web-deployment, iis-8

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application, recently we are given IIS 8 server (Windows Server 2012) and database server with SQL Server 2012. Now application sits on my local machine, talking to the SQL Server database works perfectly.

But when I deploy the application to IIS and run the app and try to let it talk to that database ... it does not and getting following warning

> The remote host does not have the dbDacFx Web Deploy provider installed, which is required for database publishing. To learn more about this visit this link.

Comment: We're going to need more than just this to be able to trouble shoot.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: are you publishing the database update along with the web-site?